# Ruby on Rails app/assets/stylesheets changes don't change public/assets/application.css

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on an existing website written in Ruby on Rails, and I'm a rails beginner. I'm having trouble changing the view of my website. I make some changes in the app/assets/stylesheets/*.css.scss but it does not change anything on the website.

In app/assets/stylesheets/application.css I have :

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree
 */
```

I've read that this should include all my css files. 
On the other hand I found the public/assets/application.css file in which the changes are directly applied but it's not a workable file.

I've found a website explaining this a bit http://www.reinteractive.net/posts/116-12-tips-for-the-rails-asset-pipeline . It tells to either include or precompile.

Does the precompile mean that it should modify the public/assets/application.css file? Because it doesn't.

I believe I'm missing something small and easy here.
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2):

By default, rails will look for assets in the 'public/assets' location. In development we usually keep modifying the assets and hence avoid using asset precompilation(i m hoping that you are using asset precompilation). what asset precompilation does is minification, concatenation of the css and js files into one single css and js file and placing them in the 'public/assets' folder.

In your case, since you are running locally in development env, remove the 'public/assets' folder altogether because right now, the application is loading the assets from there which is wrong.

Comment: hi, if I remove the public/assets. The website just appears without any stylesheets, only html code.

Comment: Could u post the contents of config/application.rb and the env file. Also, some server log of initial method would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When are you using "rails server" (development), any change on assets, will show on you application, because the rails reload all files from app/assets.
On production, the application use the compiled files on public folder, any change on application, you will need to compile the aplication again, clear the compiled files firts.

Comment: I'm testing now with rails server, but it seems that it still uses the compiled files and not the app/assets since app/assets changes do not appear on website

Comment: Any change on app/assets need to be compiled to show on production, like i said.
Try to compile and upload to website after the changes.